# How to withdraw funds in foundry test

Tags: solidity-0.8.x, foundry

I want to test a function from an existing smart contract written in solidity 0.4.

I'm using foundry/forge for that and I managed to test all the functions within this contract except the withdraw.

```
 //Old method using deprecated stuff
 function withdraw() {
        if (isPaused) throw;
        uint amount = pendingWithdrawals[msg.sender];
        pendingWithdrawals[msg.sender] = 0;
        msg.sender.transfer(amount);
    }
```

Forge test

```
receive() external payable {}

fallback() external payable {}
function test_withdraw() public {
        //Setup test
        bool isPaused = instance.isPaused();
        assertFalse(isPaused);

        vm.prank(address(1));
        instance.mint(0);
        address getOwner = instance.ownerOfIndex(0);
        assertEq(getOwner, address(1));

        vm.prank(address(1));
        instance.offer(0,1000 wei);
        offerStatus memory offer = instance.offerStatus(0);
        assertTrue(offer.isOffered);
        assertEq(offer.price,1000 wei);

        vm.deal(address(2), 1 ether);
        vm.prank(address(2));
        instance.purchase(0, 1000 wei);
        getOwner = instance.ownerOfIndex(0);
        assertEq(getOwner, address(2));
        offer = instance.offerStatus(0);
        assertFalse(offer.isOffered);
        assertEq(offer.price,0 wei);

        //test
        vm.deal(address(1), 1 ether);
        uint pendingWithdrawals = instance.pendingWithdrawals(
            address(1)
        );
        assertEq(pendingWithdrawals, 1000);
        uint balance = address(1).balance;
        console2.log(pendingWithdrawals, balance);
        vm.prank(payable(address(1)));
        instance.withdraw();
        assertEq(address(1).balance, balance + pendingWithdrawals);
    }
```

Every assertion runs fine up to `instance.withdraw()`. Than I get the following error:

```
oldContract::withdraw()
    │   ├─ [0] 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001::fallback{value: 1000}()
[FAIL. Reason: EvmError: Revert]
```

So, the assertion doesn't fail, but there's an error at the EVM.
My test check if it matches the precondition for executing the method
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Fix the withdraw function

```
function withdraw() external {
    if (isPaused) throw;
    uint amount = pendingWithdrawals[msg.sender];
    pendingWithdrawals[msg.sender] = 0;
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount);
}
```

Comment: But that should not be the issue, since this contract has been online for a while now. 

The challenge is that I can only modify what is in my test contract.